# MacOS(Catalina) terminal bash looks weird

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, macos-catalina

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSEFc.png)

I just have installed Catalina on my imac, and I saw a terminal bash looks weird.
It should be ~$ but my terminal shows ~% 
Can anyone change this uncommon line(~%) to a normal line(~$)?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your prompt can be configured by the environment variable PS1.  Here's a tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: Catalina uses `zsh`, not `bash`, as the default login shell for new accounts. You are seeing the default `zsh` prompt. It's not hurting anything, but you really have a different decision to make: learn how to use `zsh`, or learn how to change your login shell back to `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your PS1 variable in your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or .profile to whatever you want. For example:

> export PS1=“\h \W $ “

Will give your hostname, current working directory, followed by the $ you wanted. This can be customized however you like, see [this link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/amp/) for a good description.

Also, as chepner mentioned in the comments, you need to set your default shell back to bash. I believe the easiest thing to do is go into your terminal settings, and change your shell:

Terminal > Preferences... > General > Shells open with: Command (complete path): /bin/bash

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

For a long time, the bash was a default shell in macOS. However, Apple replaced Bourne Again SHell with Z shell for licensing reasons

Set default shell to bash on Macos Catalina. The procedure is as follows:

1. Open the terminal application.
2. List available shells by typing cat /etc/shells.
3. To update your account to use bash run ***chsh -s /bin/bash***.
4. Close terminal app.
5. Open the terminal app again and verify that bash is your default shell.